# Trying to create script that uses two arguments to find number of occurences within string

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I am trying to write a bash script where it takes two inputs from the user, uses the first as a three letter codon string, and uses the second as a pathname of a file containing a valid DNA string (which I have made and called dnafile.txt in my directory, and already stored a DNA string in). The script is supposed to output the number of occurrences of the codon given as argument 1 in the file given as argument 2. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grep's `-o` flag to only output matches, then count them using `wc -l` as such:

```
grep -o $1 $2 | wc -l
```

For example,

```
$ cat dnafile.txt
aacgtttgtaaccagaac
$ grep -o 'aac' dnafile.txt | wc -l
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Worked exactly as I hoped it would!

Comment: Glad it helped :)